# how to construct positive semi-definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

A positive semi-definite matrix is a matrix $A$ such that $x^TAx \geq 0$ for all vectors $x$.

So I'm wondering how we can construct one? Say a 2 by 2?

let $A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b  \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}$ and vector $(x,y)$.

then $xAx^T= x^2a+xyb+xyc+dy^2$. We need this to be bigger than or euqals to $0$. Then how do we make sure this is bigger or equals to 0?

Comment: You want an SPD matrix? Ensure the determinant is nonnegative, make the eigenvalues nonnegative.... there are so many ways.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing is that both the matrix $A$ and the vector $x$ have coefficients in real numbers.

In real numbers, you have e.g. $x^2 + y^2 \geq 0$ for all $x, y\in \Bbb R$. This means that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is positive semi-definite.